# How to get the veelo chapter style of the memoir class to pick up trimmed paper sizes?

Tags: memoir, chapters, crop

I have defined how I want to cut my paper and I was planning on using the veelo chapter style. However it doesn't pick up the trimmed paper size correctly. See this example:

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}

  \usepackage{graphicx}

  \stockaiv

  \settrimmedsize{242mm}{165mm}{*}
  \settrims{20mm}{20mm}
  \settypeblocksize{*}{33pc}{1.618}
  \setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
  \setulmarginsandblock{3pc}{3pc}{*}
  \setcolsepandrule{1pc}{0pt}

  \chapterstyle{veelo}
  \checkandfixthelayout

  \trimFrame

  \begin{document}
    \chapter{My first chapter}
    Notice how the veelo setting has not picked up the right paper size.
\end{document}
```

I have tried calling `\checkandfixthelayout` before `\chapterstyle{veelo}` also but that did not make any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your right margin does not leave enough space for the chapter number and the bar. Try

```
  \settypeblocksize{*}{25pc}{1.618}
```

Good luck,

Bastiaan Veelo.